# No camera picture when app returns from running in the background

Tags: ios, camera

I have an app using the camera. But each time the app has run in the background and you return the camera picture is gone.

Is there a trick i can make the app start over from the top each time it starts running in the foreground again?

Thank you

Comment: explain more with code and words and tags..

Comment: More information needed. How are you using the camera? UIImagePickerController or AVFoundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to the Info.plist file and set it's value to `YES`. The key is also known as "Application Does Not Run In Background" if you have the friendly key names enabled for Info.plist.

This will make your app behave as apps used to before iOS 4 where they did not suspend or multitask.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem (the big checkmark to the left) :)